# Fallas en mi código que no he podido solucionar

Tags: java

mi problema es que no me esta guardando ningun valor en las variables, si pueden opbservar tengo unas opciones para imprimir antes del break, en las variables int me aparece cero en la consola y en los string no aparece nada, al momento de correr no tiene fallos el codigo, pero nunga variable se esta guardando

ASIGNACION

Para el alta de materias, se deberá pedir la clave de la materia, la cual será alfanumérica (texto), y el nombre de la materia. No puede haber 2 claves iguales. En el nombre de la materia, puede haber más de una palabra.
Par el alta de maestros, se deberá pedir el número de nómina (entero) y el nombre del docente (puede haber más de una palabra –nombre y apellido-.
Para el alta de grupos, deberá existir materias disponibles, pudiendo haber varios grupos de la misma materia. También debe existir maestros dados de alta. Por cada grupo dado de alta se deberá generar un ID automático, iniciando desde el 1.
NOTA: en los grupos, NO se debe guardar el nombre de la materia, ni el nombre del maestro, solamente el número de la materia y el número de nómina, respectivamente.
Para la opción de mostrar grupos, se mostrará: el número de grupo, el nombre de la materia (no mostrar la clave de la materia, sino solo el nombre de la misma) y el nombre del maestro (no mostrar el número de nómina).

```
    package Asig8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        int op=0;
        Materia m1=new Materia();
        Maestro m2=new Maestro();
        Grupo g=new Grupo();
        Materia mat[]=new Materia[15];
        Maestro mtro[]=new Maestro[15];
        Grupo gru[]=new Grupo[15];
        int contMateria=0;
        int contMtro=0;
        int contGrupo=0;
        
        do {
            System.out.println("1) Alta de materias. ");
            System.out.println("2) Alta de maestros. ");
            System.out.println("3) Alta de grupos. ");
            System.out.println("4) Mostrar grupos. ");
            System.out.println("5) Salir. ");
            System.out.println("Seleccione: ");
            op=leer.nextInt();
            
            switch(op) {
            case 1:
                m1.alta();
                mat[contMateria]=m1;
                contMateria++;
                for (int i = 0; i < contMateria; i++) {
                    if((mat[i].clave).equals(mat[contMateria].clave)) {
                        while((mat[i].clave).equals(mat[contMateria].clave)) {
                            System.out.println("Ingrese una clave diferente: ");
                            mat[contMateria].clave=leer.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
                
            case 2:
                m2.alta();
                mtro[contMtro]=m2;
                System.out.println(mtro[contMtro].nomina+"   "+mtro[contMtro].nom);
                contMtro++;
                break;
            case 3:
                g.alta(mtro, mat);
                gru[contGrupo]=g;
                contGrupo++;
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i < contGrupo; i++) {
                    System.out.println(gru[i].nMateria+"  "+gru[i].nomina);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Salida exitosa");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion valida.");
            }
        }while(op!=5);
    }

}
```

Luego, en la opcion dos para ingresar un profesor, debo pedir su nomina y su nombre, al momento de guardar la nomina me la imprime en 0, y el nombre nisiquiera me deja escribirlo porque automaticamente se sale de la clase y me vuelve a imprimir el menu para ir a otra opcion

Clase Oper_maestro

```
package Asig8;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Oper_maestro extends Maestro {
    
    public void alta_maestro() {
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la nomina: ");
        nomina=leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre: ");
        nom=leer.nextLine();
        n=false;
        
    }

}
```

Clase maestro

```
    package Asig8;

public class Maestro  {
    
    int nomina;
    String nom;
    boolean n;
    
    public Maestro() {
        nomina=0;
        nom="";
        n=false;
    }
    
    public void alta() {
        Oper_maestro n=new Oper_maestro();
        n.alta_maestro();
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Pasito a pasito: esto `Materia mat[]=new Materia[15];` declara un array de `OBJECTOS` de tipo `Materia` pero **NO** los instancia. Debes hacer un bucle para recorrer cada posición y asignarles un objeto `Materia` a cada uno. Lo mismo con los array de Grupo, Maestros... Cuando tengas corregidos esos errores miramos si hay más problemas

Comment: Por cierto, en Java las clases *NUNCA* deben ir nombradas así -> `Oper_maestro` (Snake_case) si no así -> `OperMaestro` (CamelCase). Lo mismo se aplica a métodos y variables, excepto que estos empiezan por minúscula siempre.

Comment: En cuanto a que no te guarde los datos del maestro... bueno, los recoges pero *NO* los *asignas*, con lo cual tu maestro m2 sigue en blanco.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, si me ayudo, pero sigo teniendo el problema de que no me guarda nada en las variables

Comment: podrias ordenar tu pregunta y mostrar solo donde tenes el problema?

Comment: El problema que estoy teniendo es que ninguna variable se me esta guardando, al momento de correr corre sin problemas, pero nada se esta guardando

Comment: que variable? en donde la cargas? en donde la mostras? por favor, aclara todo eso...

Comment: todas las variables, se suponen que se debe mostrar en la consola al final al mostrar grupos